# How to debug a Java application running inside a Docker container using VSCode's Java debugger

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I have a Java application (`.tar`) mounted to a container. The `entrypoint` of the container starts that application.

`Dockerfile` (the backend folder is mounted into the image as a volume)

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.7

ENTRYPOINT /backend/entrypoint.sh
```

`entrypoint.sh`

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 -Xmx2048M -jar backend.jar
```

Now I want to debug that running application using VSCode's debugger. According to the official VSCode documentation ([blog: inspecting containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/31/inspecting-containers#_debug-inside-the-container)) this can easily be done with the command palette and the command `Debugger: attach to Node.js process`.

But in their example they use a Node.js server. In my container however, there is no Node.js process that I could attach the debugger to and I can't find an appropriate command for a Java Spring application. **So how can I attach the Java debugger of VSCode to an Java application which is already running inside a Docker container?**

At another place in their documentation ([containers: debug common](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/debug-common)) they state the following:

> The Docker extension currently supports debugging Node.js, Python, and .NET Core applications within Docker containers.

So no mention of Java there but then again at another place ([remote: debugging in a container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_debugging-in-a-container)) they clearly talk about a Java application:

> For example, adding this to .devcontainer/devcontainer.json will set the Java home path:
> "settings": { "java.home": "/docker-java-home" }

Comment: copy the tar file to the container and then untar it using the startup script

Comment: @Ashok how does this help me to debug the app?

Comment: basically, your requirement is that you want to execute java inside your container?

Answer (score 7):

I got a Spring Boot app to run in an **openjdk:11-jre-slim** container and was able to successfully debug it with the following configuration.

First, set jvm args when running your container. You do this via entrypoint.sh
but I decided to override my container entrypoint in docker-compose. I also expose the debug port.

```yaml
ports: 
  - 5005:5005
entrypoint: ["java","-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:5005,server=y,suspend=n","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Then add this configuration to your launch.json in vscode:

```json
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Debug (Attach)",
    "projectName": "MyProjectName",
    "request": "attach",
    "hostName": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 5005
}
```

You can now start your container and select "Debug (Attach)" under RUN AND DEBUG in VScode. This will begin your typical debug session with breakpoints, variables, etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you set up your run command like this

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -jar App.jar
```

(or however you like to call it, the important bit are the options)

Then make your docker container expose that port. I usually use a docker compose file to do that, so you can easily map the port however you like at run time

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how my setup is (I updated my question). But how can I then attach the VSCode Java debugger to that JVM?

Comment: Oh OK, there is the extension "debugger for java" that supports attaching.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: Left click on the plugins toolbar (looks like a jigsaw) then search for it.